# Automorphisms of group von Neumann algebras

Tags: group-theory, von-neumann-algebras

I study group von Neumann algebras $L(G)$, and I extremely want to know about automorophism (groups) of these algebras. Is there any good reference about this?
I appreciate of everybody help.

Comment: You can try the book $C^*$-algebras and their automorphisms by G.K. Pedersen. But I'm not sure whether he goes into much detail about the automorphisms of group von Neumann algebras.

Comment: Dear Mathematician 42 thank you very much.